# Fetch api does not work as expected from react using rails as a backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, fetch

I have a problem when I want to make a delete request using fetch api from react when I want to destroy a session(when I am logging out the user) .I get this error message **ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [DELETE] "/"):**
This is code from function log out:

```
 logOut(){
        const token=document.querySelector('meta[name="csrf-token"]').content;
        fetch("/session",{
            method:"DELETE",
            headers:{
                "X-CSRF-Token":token,
                "Content-Type":"application/json"
            }
        })
```

This is code from sessions_controller

```
def destroy
        current_user.reset_session_token!
        session[:session_token]=nil
        redirect_to "/"
    end
```

I do not pass id in url from the fetch method ,because I can get currently logged user with current_user.I get strange behavior when I reload the page the user is logged out and I do not now why is that happening.I have looked up many threads here but I did not find a similar problem.Thank you in advance.

Comment: can u post routes ?

Answer (score 0):

In your routes you need:

```
delete 'session', controller: :session, action: :destroy
```